# Missing SQLite data source in Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

After spending whole day of trying, installing, deinstalling I cannot help myself anymore. Maybe someone can give me a helping hand on it?

My problem: SQLite data source is missing when I try to add an item of ADO.NET Entity Data Model to a project. Yes, I did google and tried all suggestions I could find - without success :-(

My environment: Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2013 Express. 
I did install EF6 from NuGet (version: 6.1.3), as well as SQLite 1.0.99.0 as a bundle from SQLite page (sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.99.0.exe)

packages.config

```
<packages>
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.99.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.99.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.99.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.99.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

App.config

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sqlite design time components do not work with Express editions. You must install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. Make sure to also install the latest VS 2013 Update (currently Update 5)

Comment: Thank You Erik. Indeed readme.html says: "Due to Visual Studio licensing restrictions, the Express Editions can no longer be supported."